# Display all items of a xml using jquery when filtering

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to use a filter on xml in jquery. I am getting the filtered results based on the condition, but not able to retrieve all xml items when the flag is set to 0 ; ie when flag is zero, all xml items needs to display removing the filter.

```
JS script:
$(xml).find("TechJobSite").filter(function () {
if(jobFlagview==0) // Problem here-Have to remove the filter here to display all job lists
return ;
else if(jobFlagview==1) //My Jobs 
return $(this).find("AssignedRepairerUserName").text() == userId;
else if(jobFlagview==2) //Review
return $(this).find("Status").text() == "Draft";
}).each(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return true, instead of just `return`

```
if(jobFlagview==0)
return true;
```

---

If you don't want to apply the filter, just don't call the filter() itself like

```
var $els = $(xml).find("TechJobSite");
if (jobFlagview != 0) {
    $els = $els.filter(function () {
        if (jobFlagview == 1) //My Jobs 
        return $(this).find("AssignedRepairerUserName").text() == userId;
        else if (jobFlagview == 2) //Review
        return $(this).find("Status").text() == "Draft";
    })
}
$els.each(function () {})
```